# Bigquery performance issue today?

Tags: google-bigquery

It takes like forever to run a query or a query job with large response today. It just keep running for dozens of minutes without any errors . Those are all queries which I used in the last few days and they all went quite well.  One of those is :

```
select  sub.flag_time as flag_time 
    ,sub.hardware_id as hardware_id   
    ,t1.date_time as date_time   
    ,t1.latitude as latitude   
    ,t1.longitude as longitude   
    ,t1.zip_code as zip_code   
    ,t1.ignition as ignition   
    ,t1.speed as speed  
from 
( 
select flag_time, hardware_id, max(signature) as signature 
from fiona_test.online_actual_tmp  
group each by flag_time, hardware_id 
)as sub 
LEFT JOIN EACH 
(    
select  
     hardware_id 
    ,date_time   
    ,latitude   
    ,longitude  
    ,zip_code   
    ,ignition  
    ,speed 
    ,STRING(file_date_time)+STRING(date_time)+STRING(latitude)+STRING(longitude)+STRING(gps_valid)+STRING(ignition)+STRING(speed)+STRING(gps_reason)+STRING(zip_code) as signature  
FROM TABLE_DATE_RANGE(Geotab_test.gps32_,DATE_ADD('2014-10-01 00:00:00.339',-100,'SECOND'),TIMESTAMP('2014-10-01 23:58:20.339'))   
  GROUP EACH BY hardware_id,date_time,latitude,longitude,zip_code,ignition,speed,signature 
    HAVING (date_time BETWEEN DATE_ADD('2014-10-01 00:00:00.339',-100,'SECOND')+1 AND TIMESTAMP('2014-10-01 23:58:20.339'))  
)as t1 
ON t1.hardware_id = sub.hardware_id and t1.signature = sub.signature
```

Comment: P.S. :  "This query will process 37.9 GB when run".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an ongoing shuffler issue affecting queries that use JOIN EACH and GROUP EACH BY. We're currently investigating, it should now be fixed for new queries.

Comment: OK. Is it the reason for "Connection Error, try again" too? I got this when I run this query for a small time frame (< 1 hour) and using JOIN and GROUP BY

Comment: Yes, this could cause timeouts or even rate limit errors for concurrent queries.

Comment: When do you think it'll get back?

Comment: Everything should be back and running normally. Please ping this thread if you are still experiencing issues.

Comment: Could this issue resulted in queries returning partial results?

Comment: @JordanTigani a side track if I may. We are officially using BigQuery as the storage for our device logs. they are continuously streamed in and supporting analytical queries from all over the company. At this point, as the builder of our streaming system, I would really love to know how to measure and monitor the stream performance. Do you know any practical good benchmarks for cloud data stream? Could you give me a hint or clue? Thank you so much.